# Accessing and Editing UI Elements between Different Classes in PyQT5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am in the process of writing code that generates a main 'TopLevel' window where information is entered and then, upon the click of a pushbutton, another window opens and this information is sent through and accessed/edited/interacted with in that window. I have seemingly tried every way I can find on this website and others to try to access ui elements (be they labels, text inputs or, in this specific case, a dictionary) between different classes and nothing has worked so far.

I've edited the code below so that all the relevant elements are available and this version runs up to the point that the error is produced. The user types whatever they want in the box underneath "Input dictionary elements", clicks "Done" to add it to the list underneath "List of dictionary elements" and can then press "Expand" under the leftmost box to open the second window that I want to pass the list to.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QAction, qApp, QMenu, QLineEdit, QLabel, QTextEdit, QComboBox, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QScrollBar, QListWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QRect

def setKey(dictionary, key, value):
    if key not in dictionary:
        dictionary[key] = value
    elif type(dictionary[key]) == list:
        dictionary[key].append(value)
    else:
        dictionary[key] = [dictionary[key], value]

class TopLevel(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Top Level')
        self.resize(800,550)
        topLevelLabel = QLabel(self)
        topLevelLabel.setText('Top level of tree')
        self.topLevelBox = QTextEdit(self)
        self.topLevelBox.resize(200,50)
        self.topLevelBox.move(60,100)
        topLevelLabel.move(60,70)
        
        topLevelExpandButton = QPushButton('Expand', self)
        topLevelExpandButton.resize(50,30)
        topLevelExpandButton.move(100,150)
        topLevelExpandButton.pressed.connect(self.open_New_Window_Expand)
       
        selectSCLabel = QLabel(self)
        selectSCLabel.setText('Input dictionary elements')
        self.selectSCBox = QTextEdit(self)
        self.selectSCBox.resize(300,50)
        self.selectSCBox.move(300,100)
        selectSCLabel.move(300,60)
        selectSCLabel.resize(400,50)
        
        selectSCConfirmationButton = QPushButton('Done', self)
        selectSCConfirmationButton.resize(40,30)
        selectSCConfirmationButton.move(560,150)
        selectSCConfirmationButton.pressed.connect(self.selectSCConfirmationButtonPressed)

        listOfSelectedSCLabel = QLabel(self)
        listOfSelectedSCLabel.setText('List of dictionary elements')
        listOfSelectedSCLabel.setWordWrap(True)
        listOfSelectedSCLabel.move(60,190)
        listOfSelectedSCLabel.resize(200,30)
        self.listOfSelectedSCArea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.placeholderListItem = QWidget()
        self.vboxOfListItems = QVBoxLayout()
        self.listOfSelectedSCArea.move(60,220)
        self.listOfSelectedSCArea.resize(200,300)
        self.listOfSelectedSCArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(0)
        self.listOfSelectedSCArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(0)
        self.listOfSelectedSCArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        
        self.listOfSelectedSCDictionary = {}
        self.SCIterate = 1
        self.show() 
        
    def open_New_Window_Expand(self):
        self.new_window = QMainWindow
        self.ui = NewLevelExpand()
        self.show()
        
    def selectSCConfirmationButtonPressed(self):
        newSCName = self.selectSCBox.toPlainText()
        nameToLabel = QLabel(self)
        nameToLabel.setText(newSCName)
        self.vboxOfListItems.addWidget(nameToLabel)
        self.placeholderListItem.setLayout(self.vboxOfListItems)
        self.listOfSelectedSCArea.setWidget(self.placeholderListItem)
        setKey(self.listOfSelectedSCDictionary, self.SCIterate, newSCName)
        self.SCIterate = self.SCIterate + 1
        print(self.listOfSelectedSCDictionary)
        
class NewLevelExpand(TopLevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self, parent = TopLevel):
        self.setWindowTitle('Expanded Level')
        self.resize(800,550)
        print(self.listOfSelectedSCDictionary)

        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tl = TopLevel()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With tinkering with this code, I have generated numerous different error messages but the code above produces the message: "AttributeError: 'NewLevelExpand' object has no attribute 'listOfSelectedSCDictionary'"

As I say, I feel I have tried everything relating to this topic on stackoverflow and nothing has worked. Any advice and guidance, pointing out stupid errors, suggestions to changing my coding style to make it clearer, etc. would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit hard to help you: first of all, I'd ask you to check the indentation (read more about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)) and always ensure that the code is correctly displayed in the preview of the post; then, you should share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on *reproducible*: we must be able to copy, paste and run it), as it seems like your code is missing lots of things (mostly, UI elements like `selectSCBox`).

Comment: Thank you @musicamante for pointing out those suggestions, I thought I had reduced it down to code that others could run and edit but I realise now that I hadn't quite succeeded at that. I have edited the code above so it should run as a standalone piece and will correspondingly generate the error I am faced with.

Answer (score 0):

Premise: I cannot help you a lot with the logic behind your program; I've to admit, it's a bit confused, and I don't understand how you're going to pass data to the new window, nor how you are going to use it.

The error you're facing is because `NewLevelExpand` is a subclass of `TopLevel`, and when you call its `super().__init__()` this results in calling the ancestor's `__init__()`.

In the `TopLevel` class, `__init__()` calls `initUI`, which creates the whole UI *and* the `listOfSelectedSCDictionary` dictionary.

The problem is that you are overriding `initUI` in the subclass, so the result is that the base class `initUI` is *never* called (meaning that the UI nor the dictionary are actually created).

The solution to this specific problem is to call the base class implementation of `initUI` in the subclass:

```
class NewLevelExpand(TopLevel):
    # ...
    def initUI(self):
        super().initUI()
        self.setWindowTitle('Expanded Level')
        self.resize(800,550)
        print(self.listOfSelectedSCDictionary)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, the code now does show the second window, although it contains all the elements from the base class again which isn't what I want but is probably unavoidable due to the super().initUI call.

That's the exact problem I've trying to work out: how to pass data between the two windows. This error simply arose as a corollary of that overall issue. Is there really not an easy way to send data between classes in PyQT5? I don't even need the same UI elements from TopLevel in NewLevelExpand, I just need the data.

Comment: If you don't need the same UI elements from TopLevel, why do you subclass from it in the first place? There are dozens of possible ways to "send data between classes", it depends on how you are going to use that data. If you just need to create a new window with some data, add it to the instance constructor (for example: `newSubWindow = SubWindow(self, someData)`), and implement the `__init__` accordingly (`def __init__(self, parent, data):`). Or you can create custom signals for asynchronous communication between instances. Unfortunately, your example is too cryptic to help you more.

Comment: I hadn't found any straight answer about how to generate a new window like this, nor any mention of a SubWindow. I'm afraid I haven't had any exposure to the kind of things you mentioned in your answer: I've only been working with pyqt5 for a month or so. I may need to pass names/text from boxes or labels between windows rather than UI elements but that's what I'm hoping to use other dictionaries for. I'm relieved that you believe there are numerous ways to pass data between windows. Would you be able to point me towards some material that talks about these methods?

Comment: `SubWindow` is just an example name. And, no, there is no "material" about it, as each case is unique to its purpose, you will need to sort the programming logic out on your own. Since you are still learning, I'd suggest you to take a couple of steps back, better understand how [classes and instances](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) work, and start with *simpler* examples (for example, just pass a text variable) before already trying to do everything right now.

Comment: Of course, but your example SubWindow must be a widget of some sort, which is as good a start as any for me to learn more about this topic. Is using, for example, QMdiSubWindow a completely unreasonable idea for an initial attempt that most coders wouldn't use or not?

Comment: QMdiSubWindow should only be used in a QMdiArea. If you want a separate window you either use a QWidget or a QDialog subclass. In any case, we're going off topic, and, believe me, I cannot tell you what to do, because I really don't know what you want to do (and, even if I knew, we shouldn't discuss that here, as comments should only extend the questions and answers). You are asking for suggestions, but your objective is too broad and open to opinions (and StackOverflow is not a place to ask for opinions). Start simple, practice your code. Then, if you get stuck, ask a new question.

Comment: Completely understandable. Thank you so much for your comprehensive and patient replies, you've helped me out a great deal.